# Create a share link to a specific facebook page

Tags: wordpress, facebook, share

I am creating a Facebook share link for my Wordpress site. At the moment, I have it set up like below, which prompts a generic Facebook share (e.g., it shares on the user's wall.)

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&amp;t=<?php the_title(); ?>" title="Share on Facebook."></a>
```

Is it possible to redirect the Facebook Sharer to a specific Facebook group?  I have a Facebook page I would like users to share posts on (e.g., 
https://www.facebook.com/my-site/), and I want to direct users to that page, so they can post their article there. Can I modify the sharer so that it directs to this page, instead of the user's Facebook profile?

Comment: Unrelated: Please note that both `the_permalink()` and `the_title()` can contain characters that are not allowed in a query string.

Comment: Thanks! How could I resolve this?

Comment: No, that is not possible. The user has the option to chose to share on a page they manage within the dialog, but you can not use it to let them post to your page. If you want that kind of functionality, you have to make the post via API - after the user logged in to your app and granted it permission to post in their name.